# Angular templating not work with node.js application

Tags: angularjs, node.js, amazon-ec2, sails.js

I have a sails.js application with angular js(angular1) as frontend framework.

Routing works perfectly in `localhost` but when it comes to the living server which is an ubuntu server setup in AWS ec2 I got template not found the error.

`<ip>:1337/angular/partt.html` not found but the same path works perfectly in localhost

```
$routeProvider.
    when('/next', {
        templateUrl: '/angular/part2.html',
        controller:'NextController'
    }).
    when('/final', {
        templateUrl: '/angular/part3.html',
        controller:'FinalController'
    }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/first',
        templateUrl: '/angular/part1.html',
        controller:'FirstController'
    })
```

`part1.html` is located in `<project-folder>/assets/angular` folder .
according to sails.js doc(http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/assets) everything in `assets` folder can be accessed without `assets` prefix.

for eg: `assets/angular/part1.html` can be accessed by `localhost:1337/angular/part1.html`

Comment: As soon as I see "Ubuntu" I think "case-sensitivity". Check that you don't have any capital letters in your template file names.

Comment: Problem solved its the issue with grunt i have disabled grunt now its works